# How to refresh the table/re-route to the page after deleting

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a delete button on this page in a table. Whenever I hit the trashcan icon, it deletes in the backend, but I also want to delete it on the view. I tried to retrofit ngModel approach, but I couldn't do it; this is my first time in angular. So help would be great.

**cart.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  responsd: ViewCart[];
  respons: string;
  em: ViewCart[];
  total: number = 0;
  numb: number=12315;
  constructor(private apiControl: ApicontrolService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.populateTable();

  }
  async populateTable(){
    this.total=0;
    this.apiControl.getallcart(this.numb).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.responsd=res;
        console.log("response from cart",this.responsd);
      }
    );
    await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));

    for(let em of this.responsd){
      this.total =this.total+em.price;
    }
    console.log("total:", this.total);
  }
  deleteItem(orderid){
    this.apiControl.deleteCartItem(orderid).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.respons=res;
        console.log("response from cart",this.respons);
      }
    );
    //=====
    this.router.navigate(['components', 'cart'] );
}
}
```

**cart.component.html**

```
<p>
    <mat-toolbar>
    <span>Airtel Recharge Portal</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div>
        <h3 class=".md-title">Welcome Mr.       </h3>
    </div>

  </mat-toolbar>
</p>
<p>cart works!</p>
<div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th>Pack Name</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>  </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let cart of responsd">
                    <td>{{cart.packName}}</td>
                    <td>{{cart.price}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="deleteItem(cart.orderId)">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
                              </svg>
                       </button>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>{{total}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Comment: deleteItem(orderid){
    this.apiControl.deleteCartItem(orderid).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.respons=res;
        console.log("response from cart",this.respons);
        this.respons = this.respons.filter(obj => obj.orderid != orderid);
      }
    );
    //=====
    this.router.navigate(['components', 'cart'] );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is refresh the grid again, after the deletion happens! I have added other changes, `switchMap` will execute another observable, after the previous one completed, so first delete and then refresh. Then `tap` will assign the grid data to the variable without putting it in the subscribe. Please let me know if any doubts.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-cart',
    templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css'],
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
    responsd: ViewCart[];
    respons: string;
    em: ViewCart[];
    total: number = 0;
    numb: number = 12315;
    constructor(private apiControl: ApicontrolService, private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.populateTable().subscribe();
    }
    async populateTable() {
        this.total = 0;
        return this.apiControl.getallcart(this.numb).pipe(
            tap(response => {
                this.responsd = res;
                for (let em of this.responsd) {
                    this.total = this.total + em.price;
                }
                console.log('total:', this.total);
            })
        );
    }

    deleteItem(orderid) {
        this.apiControl
            .deleteCartItem(orderid)
            .pipe(switchMap(() => this.populateTable))
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['components', 'cart']);
            });
        //=====
    }
}
```

Comment: There were little mistakes on the code but rectifying it, it worked like a charm. Thank you so much man!

Comment: @CapedCrusader01 You're welcome! It happens :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can get to that.

1. Flush your array before fetching data :
   You can flush the `responsd` variable before fetch data, you will have something like this :

```
async populateTable() {
  this.reponsd = []; // to empty the list
  this.apiControl.getallcart(this.numb).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.responsd=res;
        console.log("response from cart",this.responsd);
      }
    );

  // the rest of your logic
}
```

then your delete method will look like this :

```
deleteItem(orderId: number): void {
  this.apiControl.deleteCartItem(orderid).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.respons=res;
        this.populateTable();
      }
    );
}
```

2. You can continue with your logic but instead of `this.router.navigate(['components', 'cart'] );`you use `location.reload()`. Then it will reload the page and you can have your list fetched from the database.

PS: I usually use the second method in my projects.

Comment: Naren's technique worked so I didnt really try yours. Thanks for the quick response tho

Comment: The most important thing is that you found a way to do it. Good luck in your programmer journey!